# Removing IMAP mail on iPhone not visible in Outlook trash

Tags: iphone, ms-office, ios

If I remove an IMAP-configured mail from a custom-domain (I've bought it via a domain-registrar), it should throw it in the trash-bin. However, these deleted mails are not visible in Outlook 2010.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug?
The mails I've deleted last (about 3 of them) are still visible in the trashbin on the iPhone, the others (about 20 or 30 of them) are gone.

Comment: Which account type do you use in Outlook? Also IMAP?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, else I wouldn't even ask it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the messages are not being trashed into the generic mail trashcan on the phone. The need to specifically be trashed in the IMAP account's trashcan.

Go to Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > (Your IMAP Account) > Account > Advanced > Deleted Mailbox and make sure Trash on the Server is selected. Not Trash on the phone.